# How to get a string from a function which has a void pointer?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, void-pointers

When I try to get a string from a function which has type `void*`, I only get the first character.

I tried to copy string manually without using `strcpy()` it gives me same problem

```
struct arr {
   int first
   int last.
   void **val; 
};

//I have a function which is called 
void *inspect_arr(const arr *ar, int position)
{
   ....
   return ar->val[offset];
}
//I want to inspect the array so that I can compare the strings
int main()
{
   char *str = calloc(10,sizeof(char));
   char *k = *(char*)inspect_arr(...) //I have a string in the array
  // strcpy(str,k);       Doesn't work
   strcmp(str,k);         Invalid read from valgrind
   //If array has an integer type then I would write my code like this:
   //int a = *(int*)inspect_arr(...) but I can not do the same thing for char
}
```

I get Segmentation fault when I run the program.

Comment: And what does the compiler say when you run the program

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: Also it all depends a lot about what these `void *` pointers should *actually be typed as*.

Comment: Provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that first `*` in `*(char*)inspect_arr(...)`.

There you dereference the pointer, getting only the first character. It's equivalent to `((char*)inspect_arr(...))[0]`.

To make it more troublesome, you then assign this single character to the *pointer* `k`. This doesn't make `k` point to the character, it make `k` point to whatever address corresponds to that characters encoded value. With e.g. ASCII and the character `'d'` the initialization is equivalent to

```
char *k = 100;
```